# OOP conditionals for greater specificity - Python

Tags: python, oop, if-statement, conditional-statements

Bit of a continuation from my previous question, using the second answer - http://tinyurl.com/n9dybgb

I'm comparing nucleotide positions in DNA where positions are in the form [chromosome, start, stop] and I have a list of existing positions, and a list of new positions. The aim is to compare the new positions list to existing positions and add one of the new positions elements if it is unique or overlaps an existing position. If it overlaps it should report it. Only if the new position element is completely contained within an existing element should it be discarded.

With thanks to @Hugh Bothwell - I currently have this code:

```
class ChromoSegments:
    def __init__(self, ChromoSegments_args=None):
        #Creates an empty default dict list which can be added to in the style "chromo[start,end]", and will stay ordered
        self.segments = defaultdict(list)
        #If a list is passed to the constructor you can add values to your list depending on conditions in 'add_seg'
        if ChromoSegments_args is not None:
            for chromo,start,end in ChromoSegments_args:
                try:
                    self.add_seg(chromo, start, end)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
    #function for adding positions to the expos list
    def add_seg(self, chromo, start, end):
        seg = self.segments[chromo]
        val = (start, end)
        ndx = bisect_left(seg, val)
        if (ndx == 0 or seg[ndx - 1][1] < start):           
            if (ndx == len(seg) or end < seg[ndx][0]):
                seg.insert(ndx, val)
            else:
                nstart, nend = seg[ndx]
                raise ValueError("Hit ({}, {}, {}) \t\t\t overlaps with ({}, {}, {})".format(chromo, start, end, chromo, nstart, nend))
        #collision with preceding element
        else:
             nstart, nend = seg[ndx - 1]
             raise ValueError("Hit ({}, {}, {}) \t\t\t overlaps with ({}, {}, {})".format(chromo, start, end, chromo, nstart, nend))

    def to_list(self):
        keys = sorted(self.segments.keys())
        return [(k, s, e) for k in keys for s,e in self.segments[k]]

def main():
    expos = ChromoSegments(expos_list)
    newpos = (newpos_list)

    error_file = open("discarded_hits.txt", "w")
    for seg in newpos:
        try:
        expos.add_seg(*seg)
        except ValueError, e:
                collision = str(e)
        error_file.write(collision + "\n")
    error_file.close()

    #convert results back into text files of positions
    updated_expos = expos.to_list()
    updated_expos_file = open(sys.argv[2], "w")
    for element in updated_expos:
        c1 = str(element[0])
        c2 = str(element[1])
        c3 = str(element[2])
        updated_expos_file.write(c1 + "\t" + c2 + "\t" + c3 + "\n")
    updated_expos_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This takes lists "expos_list" and "newpos_list" previously created and then discards all hits that have any kind of overlap with an existing element. Please can someone suggest a different/better set of if statements in the add_seg function so that only hits totally contained within an existing element are discarded? I'm really struggling to get the syntax right! Many thanks!

Example lists:

```
expos_list = [[1, 20, 40], [1, 60, 80]]
newpos_list = [[1, 12, 25], [1, 22, 38], [1, 75, 90], [1, 100, 150]]
```

So, after a successful process I would want a final expos_list (remembering that the first number (currently 1 in all cases) could be anything:

```
expos_list = [[1, 12, 25], [1, 20, 40], [1, 60, 80], [1, 75, 90], [1, 100, 150]]
```

Comment: looks like a one-dimensional geometric intersection problem. You will be able to find solution on the 'net for this.

Comment: @asmason Seems you had mixed tabs/spaces. I fixed code formatting, please check for correctness.

Comment: @alko - yeah that's fine, when I put it in the question it added spaces that weren't in my original code. Sorry about that if i edited them back out incorrectly!
Also: Ber - couldn't find anything that really helped because of the specifics. Especially the fact it's using a dictionary in this way.

Comment: 4 questions: Is the huge code example useful to understand how to insert into the list? Can you shorten the question so that more people read it? What happens if I insert `[2, 20, 40]` into `[[1, ...], ..., , [1, ...]]`? Do elements of `expos_list` always stick together in he result?

Comment: Hi @User - I know, it's long but because the functions are linked I didn't want to be asked where the variables had come from etc. The core is in the `add_seg` function, but I wanted people to have context. I was criticized in my last question for not being specific enough...  
3rd - it is treated as unique as the first number (chromosome) is different, so would be added to the list.  
4th - Stick together? Not sure what you mean, but - `expos_list` always acts as the reference, and the `bisectleft` keeps the list ordered for continual comparisons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give it a try:

```
START = 1
END = 2
expos_list = [[1, 20, 40], [1, 60, 80]]
newpos_list = [[1, 12, 25], [1, 22, 38], [1, 75, 90], [1, 100, 150]]
# sort the new list
expos_list.extend(newpos_list)
expos_list.sort(lambda l1, l2: cmp(l1[0], l2[0]) or (l1[0] == l2[0] and (cmp(l1[1], l2[1]) or (l1[1] == l2[1] and (cmp(l1[2], l2[2]))))))

# remove and print the overlaps
i = 0
l = expos_list
while i < len(l) - 1:
    if l[i][END] > l[i + 1][START]:
        print 'overlap', l[i], l[i+1]
        if l[i][START] <= l[i+1][START] and l[i][END] >= l[i+1][END]:
            # i+1 is in i
            l.pop(i+1)
        elif l[i][START] >= l[i+1][START] and l[i][END] <= l[i+1][END]:
            # i is in i+1
            l.pop(i)
        else:
            # there is a partial overlap
            i += 1
    else:
        i += 1

# overlap [1, 12, 25] [1, 20, 40]
# overlap [1, 20, 40] [1, 22, 38]
# [1, 22, 38] # removed
# overlap [1, 60, 80] [1, 75, 90]

# outcome
print expos_list
# [[1, 12, 25], [1, 20, 40], [1, 60, 80], [1, 75, 90], [1, 100, 150]]
```

This code removes all fully overlapped elements and prints all overlaps

The following line can be usefur for Python 3:

```
lambda l1, l2: l1[0] < l2[0] or (l1[0] == l2[0] and (l1[1] < l2[1] or (l1[1] == l2[1] and (l1[2] <= l2[2]))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't just want to join the lists together, but rather be selective about how `expos_list` continues. Using the above example - the chromosome region from base 20 to 40 `[1, 20, 40]`has already been added to the list. The region from base 22 to 38 `[1, 22, 38]` has therefore already been added to the list, you don't want the duplication. However, if there is an overlap (giving new sequence) this needs to be recorded - such as region 12 to 25 `[1, 12, 25]`. That's why I need an extra condition statement I think. Thanks though!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - I've adapted it to my inputs and it is working great. Nice and simple! 
Added in extra conditions for strand (where the end may be a lower number than the start) and for chromosome.